# Trying to fix kernel regression through LiveUSB not working

Tags: kernel, mount, chroot

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I haven't been able to run it any more since the latest update. I saw a related question where a user named @Fairglow called this problem a "**kernel regression**". Indeed, I can still access the Operating System via the older `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-3`**8**`generic`, but not through the more recent `Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-3`**9**`generic`. This doesn't come without problems, though.

As far as I know, there's also another question tackling a similar question, although with entirely a different problem ([System update almost broke the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828358/system-update-almost-broke-the-system%20System%20update%20almost%20broke%20the%20system)). That one, however, was marked as a duplicate of [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell). But that post doesn't solve the problem.

What happened is that I followed the steps and the commands given:

1. I created a LiveUSB for Ubuntu by using **Startup Disc Creator**
2. I booted using this LiveUSB, choosing the **Try Ubuntu** option, as advised at [ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxx does not exist. Dropping to a shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516217/alert-dev-disk-by-uuid-xxxxxxxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell)
3. I ran all the suggested commands

This is what happened:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /mnt busy
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount: mount point /mnt/dev does not exist
$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount: mount point /mnt/proc does not exist
$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount: mount point /mnt/sys does not exist
$ sudo chroot /mnt
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or     directory
$ update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media
$ update-grub
grub-mkconfig: You must run this as root
```

Therefore, the answers did not help to solve the problem, unlike mistakenly said in the last thread. I've now tried this suggestion, but it seems I am not even able to write on the disc. Any ideas how to fix this? :-(

Comment: Look at the output from the commands. They all gave errors.

Comment: @Android Dev I know, therefore I think it's absurd that the thread was closed even though the advises given there clearly don't solve the problem. I was hoping to know, though, why I get this error messages like`mount: /dev/sda1 is write-protected, mounting read-only`, or why I'm being told that the files / folders do not exist. Apparently, the instructions given to justify to close the discussion do not work. :-P

Comment: FYI - AskUbuntu is not a forum. It is a Q&A site. We have questions, not threads :) As to it being an improper dupe, you can enter the http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room chatroom, where there a lots of high-rep users like myself, who are able to re-open questions. If you explain why it isn't a dupe there, they might decide to re-open it.

Comment: @AndroidDev I know, that's why I asked a specific question concerning the problem that I am experiencing ;-) There's already on answer below where I am asking for more specific instructions

Answer (score 0):

become root but running 
    su
, create these mount points like: 
    mkdir -p /mnt/proc and try again, just make sure you are root, it sounds whole a little too difficult.

i believe grub update should be sufficient. look for:
 restoring grub after windows update 
if you need to reinstall grub loader too.
otherwise just update grub with boot directory option

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I am rather a noob on Linux, although I made the "leap of faith" directly from Windows to Linux, and there is no way going back (i.e. I am running a laptop only equipped with Linux right now)! Anyway, could you please provide a more step-by-step instructions? :-) Like; 1) what commands should I run through the terminal (I am still studying the whole process process and the logic), 2) what _mount points_ should I create and how (sorry, I don't even know what a _mount point_ is), and 3) how about the GRUB update, how to carry that out? :-P Thanks Galvani!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it is just one image failing, and you are able to boot into the system using older kernel. You definitely should do that. Upgrade the kernel once more, current version is 4.4.0-21, verify all sources are available by updating

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Attempt to upgrade all necessary

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and try again, I would suggest not using the kernel, unless you really need to. If you do, try the new version.

What would really help is a log or posting here some errors you get. Describe the trouble better.

Anyways; as far as I understand it; your system is fine. It's just one kernel failing.